# Suggestions for cloud DB for 20M+ records?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-bigquery, amazon-dynamodb

I'm going to be running an app that will have very few tables, but one table will be about 30-50K and the other will be 20-25M rows, and I'll need to be doing some queries that use a few LIKE clauses on multiple columns as well as other qualifies on columns.

The data would get refreshed monthly, so it would only be reads, no writes or updates.

Google bigQuery is proving to fall short when it comes to joins combined with the "like" searches and "order by", so I'm in a panic. A search like this actually throws a resource error or is taking hundreds of seconds to execute:

```
SELECT
s.site as site,
s.rank as rank,
s.visitors as visitors,
s.store_id as store_id,
s.currency as currency,
p.title as title,
p.product_type as product_type,
p.handle as handle,
p.price as price,
p.created_at as created_at,
p.image_url as image_url,
p.description as description
FROM eComData.stores s INNER JOIN eComData.products p
ON s.store_id = p.store_id
WHERE (
    title like '%foo%'
    OR
    product_type like '%foo%'
    OR
    description like '%foo%'
)
ORDER BY rank
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

What cloud solution would you suggest that can handle large data sets, and more importantly, speed in queries?

My options are
1) optimize Google bigQuery to run faster (not looking good)
2) Google DataStore
3) Amazon Aurora
4) Amazon DynamoDB

I'd like to hear about your experience with any of the mentioned solutions and look forward to your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using standard SQL? Legacy SQL does not automatically push filters through joins.

Comment: hmm, what research and specific issues have you found? since you included datastore, it would appear you havent researched much yet, making your question too broad. that said, look at google cloud spanner.

Comment: @ZigMandel, sorry if my question seems broad - I'm a front end guy that does php and mySQL, so I'm extremely new to big data. After looking at DataStore, I see there's no way to perform joins, so that's definitely out.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard, I unchecked Legacy SQL (oops!) and that seems to have fixed the ridiculous query times - not sure why bigQuery just throws a warning or error on that.

I had considered merging the tables into a single super table so I woudn't need to perform joins, but calling the SQL without the ORDER and WHERE clause to write to a table also doesn't seem to work - open to options on that for sure!

Comment: What do you mean by "calling the SQL without the ORDER and WHERE clause to write to a table also doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: @PatFriedl: Please accept the answer below if it helped you to achieve what you were looking for. This way, it won't be lost in thread and would help others who have similar issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data has 20M rows. It's not really big data scale at all.

Try aws redshift. It's a aws native data warehouse to store structured data. It has auto scaling built-in wherein you can scale out linearly.

- sreeni

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be ideal case to migrate to **Amazon Redshift**.

- I've worked for companies who migrate (write) analytical data which
  is more 20M+ records on a daily basis on Redshift warehouse.
  Redshift, having a column oriented is write optimised, making sure
  you have sufficient resources for querying large datasets.
- Its writes are painstakingly slow. But since you ought to read more
  than you'll write (as per your requirements - mentioned in the
  question), this'll not be an issue with you.
- The [Redshift Official Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/redshift/) is exhaustive and extensive
  support is available over the internet.
- Scaling is easy. You may add/remove nodes as per your will and
  requirements.
- However, if you have another warehouse as well, some of the functions
  for non-postgres varies. Around 90% the things remain same and this
  will not be a major administration issue. There's a list of functions / functionalities
  not supported by Redshift, which is also available in their
  documentation.
- Redshift also performs well if you have a dashboarding tool that
  needs to connect to a datasource and refreshes regularly.